# making api requests and response.json()

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a question about api request and async await

For example, I have a function as such:

```
export const getTopStories = async () => {
    const response = await instance.get(`/home.json?api-key=${api_key}`)
    const data = response.json()
    return data
}
```

is response.json() completely necessary here? I think I've also seen it where data is destructured immediately, for example,

```
export const getTopStories = async () => {
    const {data} = await instance.get(`/home.json?api-key=${api_key}`)
    return data
}
```

Does the second version work? Are they equivalent somehow?

Comment: Have you tried the two versions? What result did you get?

Comment: It seems you are confusing `fetch` with Axios. Axios returns a response object, with the `data` property. So the second version should work. The first version shouldn't work because there is no `json()` method on an Axios response.

Comment: @thchp okay that makes sense, so response.json() is only necessary and only works for fetch, got ya

Comment: fetch and axios are two different APIs. Fetch is available by default in all modern browser, while axios is a lib that needs to be imported. The avantage of axios is that it will work both on client and server whereas fetch is a client API. There is a npm package call `node-fetch` used to use fetch server-side